# How to approach this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Could someone please explain to me how I am supposed to approach and prove the following problem:

Let $I= [a,b]$ and $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $I$ such that for each $x \in I$, there exist $y \in I$ such that $|f(y)| \leq \frac 1 2|f(x)|$. 
Prove that there exist a $c \in I$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

I really have a tough time solving questions like these since I dont understand how I am supposed to start, so if someone of you are experienced could you please give me some tips about how I can possibly become better in proving such statements.

Comment: Can you find a sequence $(x_n)$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(x_n)\rightarrow0$?

Comment: I think I can, but I dont know what justification would allow me to do that? What justification or theorem would allow me to justify that?

Comment: Just your hypothesis. Set $x_1=1$. Let $x_2$ be such that $|f(x_2)|\le (1/2)| f(x_1)|$.  Let $x_3$ be such that $|f(x_3)|\le (1/2) |f(x_2)|$. Note then $|f(x_3)|\le(1/2^2)|f(x_1)|$. Continue ...

Comment: but how does that prove the existence of a c?

Comment: it does..apply the sequential definition of continuity

Comment: You will construct a monotone bounded sequence, which converges. That is one of the theorems of sequences.

Comment: Some subsequence of $(x_n)$ will converge to some $x\in I$. Apply the continuity of $f$ to this subsequence to show $f(x)=0$